# regex: find and replace

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I need to substitute the string `x(y(str))` with `z(str)`

It should also shrink the white spaces. For example:
`x ( y (str) )` should also be replaced with `z(str)`

I can write a simple perl one liner to replace 'x(y(' with 'z(':

`% echo "x(y(str))" | perl -pi -w -e 's/x\s*\(y\s*/z/g;'`

but I don't know how to replace '))' with ')' in the same one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
perl -pe's/ x \s* \( \s* y \s* (.*?) \s* \) \s* \) /z($1)/xg'
```

You probably want a leading `\b`.